# Compare values on GridView and set backgroud color cell depending on condition

Tags: c#, gridview

The **GridView** in markup page on aspnet is populated from sql query below.

In **row number 2**, I have a  limit value not to be exceeded, in this case the value is 225.

In **row number 1**, I have a value registered on database, in this case the value is 6534.

Now I need to compare these values and if the value of **row number 1** is higher of value of **row number 2**, I need set the background color of label in **GridView** it must be red.

I thought to solve with **RowDataBound**, but without success because I have error :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection parameter name:index

Please help me out.

My code below.

**Sql Query**

```
mysql> SELECT
    H2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            H2
        FROM
            `listValue`
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                H2_PPM
            FROM
                `listfiles`
            WHERE
                ID = 17819
    ) tbl
GROUP BY
    H2
HAVING
    count(*) = 1;
+------+
| H2   |
+------+
| 225  |
| 6534 |
+------+
2 rows in set
```

**OnRowDataBound**

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int ValH2 = Convert.ToInt32(gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text);

        //tried also int ValH2 = Convert.ToInt32(gv.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text);
    }
}
```

**GridView Label**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H2" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbH2" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:N0}", Eval("H2"))%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Edit #02**

[image: **Edit #02**]

**Edit #01**

```
Line 275:        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
Line 276:        {
Line 277:            int ValH2 = Convert.ToInt32(gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text);
Line 278:        }
Line 279:    } 

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index    Line: 277 

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index]
   System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +14540872
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +19
   Default.gv_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet\Default.aspx.cs:277
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e) +137
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, 
   DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, 
   PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +262
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +5059
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +97
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +18
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +165
   Default.BindData() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet\Default.aspx.cs:86
   Default.btnInc_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet\Default.aspx.cs:197
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +141
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +186
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5028
```

Comment: Can you either post a [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a complete stack trace.

Comment: @Aron Please see my **Edit #01** in first question, thanks

Comment: Either .Rows or .Cells is an empty collection. You need to see why that is, possibly because data hasn't been bound yet, or because they SQL returned an empty set of results.

Comment: @Aron Please see my **Edit #02** in first question, thanks. It's the output in gridView